# line 39: [: ==: unary operator expected

Tags: arrays, bash, unary-operator

I am trying to generate a password with certain requirements.
When I enter the while loop to generate a random character from the array it is fine until I add a count for my index "$i"

With the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SET ARRAY VALUES
all=( 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z )

echo

#SET COUNT VALUES TO 0
numc=0
lowc=0
upc=0
i=0

while true;
do
#GENERATE PASSWORD
phrase[$i]=${all[$RANDOM%62]}
    #CHECK IF PASSWORD MEETS REQUIREMENTS
    for ((n=0; n<10; n++))
    do
            if [ ${phrase[$i]} == ${all[$n]} ]
            then
            echo num ${all[$n]}
            let "numc++"
            let "i++"
            fi
    done
```

I get the error "line 39: [: ==: unary operator expected"

but if I remove the `let "i++"` line then there is no error. But I need to increase my index in order to exit the loop and check the minimum length of the password

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using a password generator like those in most password storage applications or [`pwqgen`](http://www.openwall.com/passwdqc/)? Is this an assignment?

Comment: `all=( {0..9} {a..z} {A..Z} )`

Comment: yes its an assignment so I need to create a password generator on my own

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `${phrase[$i]}` (by the way you don't need `$` in `[$i]` context `${phrase[i]}` works too) is ever the empty string that `if` test will become `[ == value-of-all-n ]` which isn't a valid test.

Either quote the variables (which is almost always the right thing to do) or prevent that from ever being the empty string. (Was that `i++` supposed to happen outside the inner loop?)